# QuickSight send scheduled email SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

With Amazon QuickSight UI we can schedule the emails weekly, daily or monthly. Can we use SDK to schedule the emails on QuickSight? I have searched the documentation but I am able to find any endpoints or API.

Can this be done with SDK (PHP preferred)? What will be the steps involved if so?

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search returned this AWS Documentation for quicksight SDKs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/quicksight-sdks.html

Sadly there are no code for PHP. But it should get you started. If you're looking for code with you specific requirement then again you can't find it here. Share what you have and community might help you with issues in your code.

Comment: Yep i am aware of the sdk. In fact i have used sdk to create and manage dashboards. But i am not able to find out the documentation that deals with setting the schedules for email notification through email.